# Transformation of a continuous random variable and the corresponding probability density function - where is my mistake?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, cumulative-distribution-functions

Suppose for a random variable $X$ I have probability density function $f_{X}(x) = 4x^{3}$, for $0<x<1$, and $f_{X}(x) = 0$ otherwise. I'd like to find probability density function of random variable $Y = 2X-1$.

My solution: I simply rearrange the expression to get $X$ in terms of $Y$, i.e. $X = \frac{Y+1}{2}$. The range for $Y$ is $-1<Y<1$. Then I simply rewrite density function in terms of $y$ to get

$f_{Y}(y) = 4\left(\frac{y+1}{2}\right)^{3}, \qquad -1<y<1$,

and $f_{Y}(y) = 0$ otherwise.

However it turns out this is wrong, and we should have $f_{Y}(y) = 2\left(\frac{y+1}{2} \right)^{3}$, so basically my answer is wrong by a numerical factor (I have $4$ instead of $2$ ). Why does my approach of simply replacing the old variable in the formula for probability density function by the expression for the new variable in terms of old variable lead to an incorrect answer?

Answer (score 1):

It's essentially because of the chain rule.  If you look at the CDF, we have $\mathbb{P}(Y \le y) = \mathbb{P}(2X-1 \le y) = \mathbb{P}(X \le \frac{y+1}{2})$.  Now we compute
\begin{align*}
f_Y(y) &= \frac{d}{dy} \mathbb{P}(Y \le y) \\
&= \frac{d}{dy} \mathbb{P}\left(X \le \frac{y+1}{2}\right) \\
&= \frac 12 f_X\left(\frac{y+1}{2}\right) \\
&= 2 \left(\frac{y+1}{2}\right)^3.
\end{align*}

Comment: So in simple terms, we have by chain rule that $f_{Y}(y) = \frac{dP}{dy} = \frac{dP}{dx} \frac{dx}{dy}$ and here $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{2}$, right?

Comment: I understand how the chain rule gives the correct answer, but I still don't understand what is it why does my approach of simply rewriting the expression in terms of a new variable leads to a missed factor...? @user6247850

Comment: I agree that is somewhat odd from an intuition point of view.  I guess I would say that, if you think of the pdf as a density, when you define $Y = 2X-1$ you are spreading out $X$ over a wider area.  So when you look at the density of $Y$ at a point $y$, you have to take into account not just the density of $X$ at the corresponding $y$, but also the fact that $X$ is stretched out over an area twice as large now, making it half as dense.